# CSS Code Organization Techniques

Tags: css

This is probably a borderline question because I'm not sure there's a right answer, but I'm curious as to how people organize their stylesheets, and if there's a common practice. I'm sure it comes down to personal style, but I'd still like to see what some people do differently.

Global styles are always up top, and the rest of the styles are generally written in the order that they appear on the page.

I tend to indent all sub-styles, subclasses, and pseudo-classes under the parent class:

```
#search {
    float:right;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:325px;
    height:35px;

    background-image:url(css-ref/main.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    text-align:right;
    line-height:36px;
    font-size:13px;
}
    #search a:link,#search a:visited,#search a:active {
        color:#333;
    }
    #search a:hover {
        color:#1770a9;
    }
```

Within a class, I always list properties in the following order:

```
.myClass {
    [position, display, and float]
    [margins and padding]
    [width and height]
    [background, border, border-style, shadow]
    [font settings]
    [animations/transitions]
}
```

For me, this improves readability because things are always going to be in the same order if I need to go through and find a property within a particular class.

Are there better/more accepted ways of organizing stylesheets? How do you do it?

Comment: If its good for you, thats all that matters. All developers have different ways of doing things, just make it understandable for other developers, and optimum for yourself

Comment: There are some good tips here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners/. But as Andy said, there is no one best way. If it works for you, it's probably alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identation or "nesting" is a common practice and is a key feature of CSS meta-languages like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules).

Comment: To add on, google recommend 2 spaces for indentation, not tabbing or 4 spaces: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml

Comment: Why two spaces? Does it take longer to compress the whitespace with tabs?

Comment: @Jon the recommendation is to decrease readability and to take away the ability to control the indentation level in my editor.

Comment: @Jon: That recommendation shows that Google doesn't know everything either. Recommending "some number of spaces" (here 2) instead of tab shows that one doesn't understand what a tab is. A tab is one level of indendation, and not equivalent to any number of spaces. It just isn't the same class of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice way. FYI I find no extra readability from indenting the code. Therefore I don't. http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/initial-css-settings.php